# `gulp.src` vs `vinyl-source-stream`?

Tags: gulp, filestream

Have been looking through some gulp files. I couldn't help but notice that for some of the tasks `gulp.src(...)` was being used to source the files. However, for other tasks (like when using browserify) `var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');` & `.pipe(source('bundle.js'))` were used.

I take it that the `vinyl-source-stream` stream type is what gulp uses to source the file, but since browserify was being used directly, we needed to convert its stream type to one compatible with gulp. However, if that is really the case... then what was the purpose of `buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');` & `.pipe(buffer())` because apparently the `buffer()` is what does the conversion.

[ref: https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-browserify]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vinyl-source-stream` transforms readable streams into vinyl objects.

`vinyl-buffer` transforms a streaming vinyl into a buffer vinyl.

A vinyl object can wrap a [stream or a buffer](http://www.codingdefined.com/2015/12/difference-between-buffering-and.html), and `gulp.dest` accepts both. However, several gulp plugins doesn't accept streaming vinyls. In fact, a

> streaming not supported

error is pretty common when you start to work with gulp. For examples, afaik, there are not nodejs minifiers that support streaming vinyls: you need `gulp-buffer` for make your current stream to work with such plugins.

Vinyls generated from `gulp.src` are buffers, but vinyls generated with `vinyl-source-stream` from a readable stream (`browserify.bundle()` returns a readable stream) aren't, so `vinyl-buffer` will be need to use several plugins with that, like uglify.

so, you don't really need `vinyl-buffer` to make *just* browserify and gulp to work together. This really simple gulp task will work properly:

```
gulp.task('browser' , function(){

    return browserify({
            debug: true,
            entries : './browserify-script.js'
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe( source('browserify-script.js') )
       // .pipe( buffer() ) //you don't need this, 
       //since gulp-dest accepts both streams and buffers
        .pipe( gulp.dest('./scripts/'));

});
```

However, to use the `gulp-uglify`plugin, you will need `buffer`:

```
gulp.task('browser-ugly' , function(){
    return bundler = browserify({
            debug: true,
            entries : './browserify-script.js'
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe( source('origin.js') )
        .pipe( buffer() ) //you cannot get rid of this.
        .pipe( uglify() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest('./scripts/'));
});
```

Since `uglify()` expects a buffer. Cut out the `.pipe( buffer() )` line will result in a 'streaming not supported' error from the uglify plugin.

However, you usually don't need to *buffer()* with gulp, because `gulp.src` generates buffer vinyls from the beginning:

```
gulp.task('gulp-uglify' , function(){

    gulp.src('simple.js')
    .pipe( uglify() ) //no need to buffer()
    .pipe( gulp.dest('./scripts'));
});
```